# Lightning Out and instance URL

Tags: lightning-out

I have an external JS app that uses oAuth (JWT flow) to authorize itself to Salesforce. After the authorization step, my external app loads a Lightning Out component.

The response from SF oAuth token endpoint contains `instance_url`. The instance_url has the pattern `https://yourInstance.my.salesforce.com`.  If I use `...my.salesforce.com` url  in my js script to load a Lightning Out component, the operation fails. If I use `...lightning.force.com` it works.

I don't want to hardcode the instance URL. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity -- why do you need another URL? Doesn't returned one work?

Comment: `..lightning.force.com` is not a My Domain login URL. Use what you got

Comment: Yes, if I use the url with my.salesforce.com in my js script to use lightning out it fails, but by using url lightning.force.com it works, but this last one I only can put it on code "hard coded"

Comment: Note that lightning.force.com will always be constant there so you just need the domain and this will not change